# Compare Select Values and on Change disable the already selected values

Tags: jquery

I need to disable the select box values moving in order. For eg:

```
<div>Box 1 has 10,20,30,40            Box 2 has 10,20,30,40</div>
<div>Box 3 has 10,20,30,40            Box 4 has 10,20,30,40</div>
```

Now if I select **10** from **Box 1** so in **Box 2** **10** should be disabled and similarly If I select **30** from **Box 3** so **10,20,30** will be disabled from **Box 4**. I am already able to achieve this part. Now I am left with I want to link these as I have **selcted 20** from **Box 2** , I WANT TO DISABLE EVEN IN **BOX 3** TILL **20** i.e in **BOX 3**, I should **not be able to** select **10,20**.
Here is the [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rigid/wzypqLxx/).
The main thing is I cant change my HTML structure.
Here is the JS code

```
$('.specialSelect').each(function(j) {
   var selId    =   $(this).attr('id');
   //alert(selId);
   $(this).children('.selmin1').on('change', function() {
      var sel2option    =   $(this).children('.selmin2').find('option');
      sel2option.prop('disabled', false);
      // get selected index of select1
      selIndex  =   $(this).children(".selmin1 option:selected").index();
      // disable all indexes below selected index
      $('#'+selId+' .selmin2 option').each(function(i) {
        if(i<=selIndex){
           $('#'+selId+' .selmin2 option[value="' + this.value + '"]').prop('disabled', true); 
        }
     })
  });
});
```

Please any help is really appreciated.

Comment: So if you select 10, you cannot select 10 in any of the boxes? If you select 20 in box 3, they should all have 20 disabled?

Comment: if i select 20 in box 2 so till 20 it should be diabled in box 3, eg: in box 2 i select 30 so box 3 should have 10,20,30 disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Script**

```
// Get all select box
var allSelects = $('select'); 
var length = allSelects.length;
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('select').change(function(){
      // Get index of selected option of current select box
      var selection = $('option:selected', this).index(); 

      // Get the index of next Select box
      var index = allSelects.index(this) + 1; 

      if(index < length){
         // Get next select box
         var nextSelect = allSelects.eq(index);

        // Make option disable
         $('option', nextSelect).each(function(i){
           if(i <= selection)
             $(this).prop('disabled', true);
           else
             $(this).prop('disabled', false);  
         });
       }
   });
});
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/913a5tqm/

Comment: This works perfect in chrome but for firefox see http://puu.sh/i8znK/be2d46c985.png
I am able to select value in 4 boxes.

Comment: it actually works fine both Chrome and Firefox. But the problem is you have to change selected value of the particular select box to disable next one option.

Comment: Example: select box 2 already select 30 and you again select 30. in this case it doesn't disable next one option as you don't change the value. To disable next one you must have to change the selected value.

Comment: @user930026, I updated the answer. See the answer again.

Comment: Hi, Thanks.. Works perfect now. Can I Request something more if it is possible. Can it be like
Box 1 - 10 n if Box 2 has 30
Box 3 should be available from 30
AM sorry for new request again but if its possible so like 2 Box and Box 3 and then similarly Box 4 with Box 5 can have same but not less
Eg it can be 
Box 1 - 10      Box 2 - 40
Box 3 - 40      Box 4 - 60
Box 5 - 60      Box 6 - 90

Comment: I actually don't understand what you said. Explain a bit more.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to make a series like
10-30
30-50
50-80
so here as u can see box 2 n box 3 have same i.e 30 n box 4 n box 5 have same 50

Comment: I have marked but as per my new request, can you please suggest how to achieve this. 
10-30
30-60
60-80

Comment: did you want to remove 10-20 from Box-3 and 10-50 from Box-5 rather than disable?

Comment: Generally range means between something. here these boxes are actually min-max range.. so, like if a student scored 35, he will be in range 30-60 and if he scored 29 then he will be in range 10-30 that is the reason, i want that as the result will be unique always so currently what is happening is 10-30 and then 40-60 so in this case students scoring between 30-40 will have no range message. Hope u understood, what i seek